# api to find company of logged in user when the user is part of google apps domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client, google-identity-toolkit

I am trying to create an app for some of my customers who are using google apps domain. I wanted to use google services to distinguish the users based on their company name. I was trying to figure out which API is useful for this scenario.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What do you mean by 'company name'?

Comment: I don't think there is such an API. Maybe just use the domain from their email address?

Comment: @Mike, my intention is organization name or some organization id that user belongs to. When I have gone through the API, it says admin can create multiple org-units for a user. If that is the case, I wanted rootlevel orgnization name or id to distinguish between users from two different companies.

Comment: @abragam: a company can have multiple domains configured under same google apps account (may be when aquired a new company https://support.google.com/a/answer/182452). In such case relying on email address domain name may not be good.

Comment: For instance, when we are using office 365 api, it gives something like tenant id which is different for each company through which we can identify user's company user has been authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider retrieving the unique Customer Id via the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-org-units) rather than a 'Company Name'. You would do this by retrieving a ***user*** using the [users.get() API call](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_user).

Keep in mind that Company Name is not always the domain, nor would there always be just one Company Name (there can be one for every OU). Having said this, you can retrieve the Organisation name via the same API. You should refer to the organizations field.

With regards to your comment about readonly access to domain users, perhaps add the constraints under which you are trying to solve this in your question as we cannot possibly guess without you providing information.

Comment: From the Directory API, I find CustomerId is the common thing for the users of same GoogleApp account. I am wondering if I can get this data from non-admin APIs. As in my scenario, users on logging, I must be distinguishing the users based on this. Hence, only with user authentication I must be able to get this information. Is there any way to get this information without admin providing credentials.

Comment: What do you mean by 'non-admin' APIs?

Comment: Like plus api to get profile information which does not require admin credentials.

Comment: What about People.get which returns organization(s)?

Comment: I was trying this option, but I could not get the organization details when invoking this API.

Comment: my problem is almost same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316835/how-can-i-retrieve-the-customerid-from-a-using-google-api-calls-from-a-nonadmin 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327314/how-to-get-a-customerid-or-other-primary-key-for-a-google-apps-account